# Change the foreground/background colours of the line number in DBeaver SQL Editor

Tags: dbeaver

In DBeaver 23.2.1 on Linux Mint 21.2, there is an odd background colour appearing when I press enter in the SQL editor.  I can't find what preference is causing this, or even just how to change its colour.

Screenshot with red square showing the part I'm referring to:

[Link, as I don't have the rep to post pic inline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvN7W.png)

Ideally, I want to get rid of this odd highlight, or at the very least, change it's colour.

Does anyone know if it's possible?

Thanks!

***EDIT: Found the answer myself!***

It's the Quick Diff option that's causing that behaviour.  I just turned it off, but there are options there to change colours etc.

[This is the setting in case anyone else runs in to the same issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7NS0.png).

Comment: In the official documentation there is a dedicates section discussing colorization that may be also useful: [Default Data Grid colorization and how to change it](https://dbeaver.com/2022/07/28/default-data-grid-colorization-and-how-to-change-it/).